# Control iPhone Services using Low--Level API or PrivateFrameworks in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios, jailbreak, cydia, low-level-api

I am trying to make put together a simple application to control the phone services such as WiFi, Bluetooth, 3G, etc. using Private Frameworks or low-level API's.  I am able to build the device and SSH it to my device without a dev account, and I have the SDK headers, but I am looking or some help in adding these Private Frameworks to my app. I am receiving all kinds of errors when I try to follow the Erica Sadun directions. I am building the app for 3.0.

Does anyone know how to add these Private Frameworks to your project and correctly import and use them for OS3.0? Or if anyone wants to help me develop this project, please contact me!

**EDIT:** See my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694745/error-iphone-private-frameworks-no-such-file-or-directory/1767537#1767537).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get PrivateFrameworks to work correctly in 3.x SDK, make sure that HEADERS and BINARIES are in the following folders:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks

for example:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/Headers/BluetoothManager.h
```

-and-

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager <-- binary
```

NOW your able to implement:

```
#import <BluetoothManager/BluetoothManager.h>
```

-and you can control bluetooth radio in your app.