# ERROR: iPhone Private Frameworks "No such file or directory"

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cydia, iphone-privateapi

I have added Private Frameworks To my project. When I build in DEVICE | RELEASE everything works fine and I am able to ldid -S the application and it successfully launches on my device.

However, when trying to BUILD AND GO in Simulator, I get the error "No such file or directory" as indicated below: (I also get the error twice which is strange too.)

```
 Line Location HomeProfileViewController.h:10: error:  BluetoothManager/BluetoothManager.h:  No such file or directory
```

Below are the project and build settings that I currently have, maybe someone can find a mistake and let me know, that would be awesome!

**PROJECT SETTINGS:**

```
PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH = "/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/Versions/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/include"
PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH = "/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/Versions/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/include"
USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/Versions/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/include"

OTHER_CFLAGS = "-I/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/Versions/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/include-I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/include-I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin9/4.0.1/include-F/System/Library/Frameworks-F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks-F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks-DMAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED=1050"
```

**TARGET BUILD SETTINGS:**

```
PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH = "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks"
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(inherited) $(SDKROOT)$(SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR)/PrivateFrameworks"
USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/Versions/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/include/**"

OTHER_CFLAGS = "-I/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/Versions/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/include-I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/include-I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin9/4.0.1/include-F/System/Library/Frameworks-F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks-F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks-DMAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED=1050"
```

Note: The quotation marks in the paths aren't actually in my project, I put them in so the site will syntax them better.

***Cydia***

Comment: do you want to be rejected from the app store? :S

Comment: Just a retag. This app is in Cydia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, for SDK 3.0+, make sure that binaries and headers are in the PrivateFrameworks folder like the following example:
**/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework**

Binaries and Header files must be under this directory, headers must be under /Headers, for example:
**/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/Headers/BluetoothManager.h**

then use these statements where you will need the private headers:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    //This is where you put code for simulator
#else
    //Private functions will go here!       
#endif
```

NOW you can add the private framework from the first directory listed above, and you can build and go for simulator, and build for device! YOu wont have to add/delete frameworks when switching between device/simulator!

Comment: Thank u a lot man! I rly appreciate it! I created pop up if BLTH is power off, with 2 buttons and 2-nd button can enable BLTH.